# Android Studio ArrayAdapter and ListView error

Tags: android-studio

When I tried to add a list to a listview using an ArrayAdapter, I got this error ('getOnItemClickListener ()' in 'android.widget.AdapterView' cannot be applied to '(anonymous android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)').[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PScFd.png)

Comment: Try using setOnItemClickListener()